# How to leave nomenclature list out of table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, nomenclature

In my thesis, I have a table of contents, list of figures, list of tables and a list of symbols and nomenclature generated with `nomencl` (in that order).

The lists of figures and tables do not appear in my table of contents. But, for some reason, my list of symbols and nomenclature does. How can I prevent the list of symbols and nomenclature from showing up in the TOC?

I am generating my list of symbols with the commands `\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols and Nomenclature}` (just to rename it to include both symbols and very brief definitions). Then: `\printnomenclature[5cm]` to print the list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`nomencl`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nomencl) package provides two options in this regard:

- `intoc`: Inserts the nomenclature in the Table of Contents.
- `notintoc`: No entry for the nomenclature in the Table of Contents. (default)

To revert to the default, use

```
\usepackage{nomencl}% http://ctan.org/pkg/nomencl
```

or insert the package option `notintoc` for completeness

```
\usepackage[notintoc]{nomencl}% http://ctan.org/pkg/nomencl
```

This will remove the "List of Symbols and Nomenclature" from the ToC.